# Reference request for a binomial identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I stumbled upon the following (perhaps well-known) identity for a positive integer $k$:
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)j+1}\binom{kj}{j}\binom{k(n-j)}{n-j}=\frac{1+kn}{1+(k-1)n}\binom{kn}{n}.$$

Could you please give me references where I can find a proof?

Comment: Your identity can be obtained from identity $(2)$ in the paper W. Chu, "Elementary Proofs for Convolution Identities of Abel and Hagen–Rothe" by applying formula $\binom{\alpha}{s}=(-1)^s\binom{s-1-\alpha}{s}$ to all binomial coefficients.

Comment: @nemo: I have corrected the typo.

Comment: @nemo: Thank you for mentioning the Hagen-Rothe identity. This solves my question. Why did you not post your comment as answer?